# making Mirrored Right Traingle through for loops in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help making a mirrored right triangle like below

```
     1  
    21
   321
  4321
 54321
654321
```

I can print a regular right triangle with the code below

```
print("Pattern A")
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(1,i):
        print(j, end="")
    print("")
```

Which prints

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
```

But I can't seem to find a way to mirror it. I tried to look online on how to do it but I can't seem to find any results for python and only examples for Java.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one using the new f-string formatting system:

```
def test(x):
    s = ""
    for i in range(1,x+1):
        s = str(i) + s
        print(f'{s:>{x}}')

test(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works. I loop over the amount of lines, add the whitespace needed for that line and print the numbers.

```
def test(x):
    for i in range(1,x+1):
        print((x-i)*(" ") + "".join(str(j+1) for j in range(i)))

test(6)
```